# Databricks - Failure Starting REPL

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-analysis, databricks

I am using a databricks cluster to run some ETLs.

During the night, there is a peak in executions, no library is installed during executions.

Spark version is 3.2.0 and scala version is 2.12. Runtime 10.2.

During the execution peaks, sometimes a failure to start the python REPL causes a failure in some
notebooks that are vital to the process.

The error can be seen in the first image.

This error is happening since last month. I have incresead the max executors from 2 to 3, but the erros is still happening some days. The cluster information can be seen in the second image. The peak generally executes 50 ETLs at the same time.

The failure happened between 10:05 and 10:15.

Worker information can be found in the third image.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX5Ai.png)

[Memory and CPU info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoA0N.png)

[Cluster Worker Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqaO8.png)

Comment: Are you using  Spot instances? If so can you please configure all the 3 nodes as On Demand and test it?

Comment: Also in the second image, I see the usage is above 100%, try to scale with more nodes say 5 or 6  (no SPOT instances), and test it for a few days.

Comment: I am not using Spot. Cluster mode is High Concurrency with unrestricted policy. I Thought that maybe using a 64gb 8 core Driver should help. When the problem happen, the cluster continues Online. Actually, when the failure happened, the env was running with just 2 workers, but the max is 3 workers, so it was not at its maximum.

Comment: In the second image Memory and CPU info,  (top left) you will see one node is down. Thats the reason you are noticing 2 hosts. 

For Jobs Standard job cluster is best suited as it will help you to identify the errors caused by your application. With HC you may run into risk of other apps sharing the cluster. 

Please check the Driver Log for that given time to see what is causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the real issue was the Driver.

The max workers were set to 3, but sometimes, during the execution peak, the number of worker remained 2. Exploring the issue, I identified that the whole problem happened during the commands interpretation, not during tasks processing. So, the driver suffered to proccess all the code and organize the tasks during this peak.

The easy solution was to increase tha machine memory and cores, but this would cause a increase of US$ 10 000 per year (Only driver) and US$ 10 000 per Year per worker. (20 hours a day, every day). Because of the cost, I decided to develop something similar to a job Pool. Which limits the number of executions sent to the driver and spread them during the time.

This solution solved the problem and saved a cost of up to US$ 40 000 during the next 365 days of operation.

Comment: We are having the same issue. Can you share some more details on how you implemented the "job pool" solution? Do you refer to a "job" as in a scheduled notebook? Or do you limit the actual load within a notebook? Or do you refer to another method to reduce the load on the driver?

Comment: In my case, the repl error happened only in our prod environment, and that too, only when I was loading a custom whl python library via the databricks UI. I ended up removing the whl file from the UI, copying the whl file of the library into dbfs and loading it into the cluster via an init script to resolve the issue. 

But it's very annoying that the exact same version of Databricks just works fine with the library in our UAT and dev environments when uploaded via the UI.